# Cambiar puntero de linea en un txt para agregar algo usando una misma declaración with que modifique en una linea de ese txt y luego modifique en otra

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, filewriter, filereader

```py
association_path = 'data_association/definition_file.txt'
line_1st_index = 1 #Por ejemplo este numero de indice de linea

with open(association_path,"r+") as f:
    lineas = [linea.strip() for linea in f.readlines()]

    f.truncate(0)
    f.seek(0)
    lineas[line_1st_index] = "lo que agrega en la linea" #En la redefinicion NO es necesario el salto de linea
    f.writelines("\n".join(lineas))

    #----------------------------------------
    #Aca esta el problema en donde quiero agregar el salto de linea al final de este mismo txt
    lineas[-1] = ""
    f.writelines("\n".join(lineas))
    #----------------------------------------
```

Estaba intentando cambiar el contenido de la linea de indice 2, lo cual consigo, pero luego dentro de la misma declaración `with` , ya que es el mismo archivo y no quiero cerrarle y volverlo abrirle con un `with open(association_path,"a") as f:`, quiero ir hasta la ultima linea y agregar un salto de linea de modo que quede una linea vacia al final del txt.

Asi es como esta el txt antes de ejecutar el programa:

```
un software optimizado
un liquido
una planta de desierto
```

Y asi me esta quedando luego:

```
un software optimizado
un fluido
una planta de desiertoun software optimizado
un fluido
```

La linea de indice `1` consigue cambiar `un liquido` por un `un fluido`, pero al final en lugar de solamente agregar el vacio `""` con el `\n` agrega todas las lineas.

En lugar de eso deberia quedar tan solo con el cambio en la linea de indice `1` y el salto de linea al final, dejando una linea vacia a lo ultimo:

```
un software optimizado
un fluido
una planta de desierto
```

Comment: Te está repitiendo las líneas al final porque tú le has pedido que añada las líneas repetidas al final, en la instrucción `f.writelines("\n".join(lineas))`, ya que `lineas` es una lista que contiene todavía todas las líneas (aunque hayas cambiado la última por ""). Si tan sólo querías añadir un retorno de carro al final de fichero, haz eso, es decir `f.write("\n")`

Comment: Muchas gracias!!, ahi lo corregi, por cierto de casualidad sabes como haria eso mismo `f.write("\n")` en caso de querer agregar algo en otra linea que no fuese necesariamente la ultima, indicando el indice de dicha linea?

Comment: Me temo que no puedes hacer eso en el fichero (o yo no sé cómo). Hasta donde yo sé, si haces un `fseek()` para colocarte en algún lugar del fichero y luego escribes, eso va a truncar el fichero en ese punto, de modo que se pierde todo lo que venía después. El enfoque para este caso sería leer el fichero completo a una lista python, con `readlines()` para luego insertar en esa lista donde quieras (`lista.insert()`) y finalmente sobreescribir el fichero entero volcando de nuevo la lista (`f.write("\n".join(lista))`)

Comment: Gracias de nuevo!, lo de cargar las lineas en una lista de lineas y agregar la nueva linea como un elemento en medio esta interesante para esos casos.